# WSO2 ESB Sample Service List

Tags: console, admin, sample, wso2-esb

I'm having trouble understand how WSO2 Proxy services are viewed.
I went through the tutorial to create and use the SimpleStockQuotesServices proxy service, and that went just fine.

Then I shut down the ESB, and started it up with sample 0 configured 
(ie: `./wso2esb-samples.sh -sn 0`) and that worked fine.
I started the backend axis server, and that worked fine too.
I ran the sample `ant stockquote -Daddurl=http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService -Dprxurl=http://localhost:8280/` and it worked fine too.
Everything is great.

When I go to the admin console, and look at the list of deployed services     `https://localhost:9443/carbon/service-mgt/index.jsp?region=region1&item=services_list_menu`
The page shows three services (echo, Version, and wso2carbon-sts).  not the SimpleStockQuoteSercice that I was expecting.  If I shut off the ESB, it all fails

My question, is, Where is it listed?
I guess that the ESB is just redirecting `http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService` to `http://localhost:8280/services/SimpleStockQuoteService`, but I'm not sure, and I was really expecting to see the stock quote service.  What's going on?

When I ran through the tutorial, I created a SimpleStockQuoteService, and when I started up sample set zero, I assumed that it would start up a similar SimpleSTockQuoteService on the ESB.

Comment: So, I can't see the mediators on the list of deployed services, because I was looking at the wrong place.  I 'think' that when I set up the samples, the ESB has just one IN and one OUT sequence set up.  the invocation of the stockquote service goes through the 'default' IN and OUT sequences, so there is no proxy to see.  Or, at least that's what's happening with sample 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleStockQuoteSercice is deployed inside the backend axis2 server and not inside ESB. What happens here is that ESB sits in-between the client and the backend axis server, mediating the messages.

In this sample, requests are sent to the ESB (`http://localhost:8280/`) and the ESB then sends them to the backend axis2 service (`http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService`). You can find more info on the parameters used for this client [here](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Using+the+Sample+Clients#UsingtheSampleClients-StockQuoteclient).